# VB.NET unit test project create an instance of another project

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing

I have a built out project called MyProject that I want to start unit testing. 
I created a unit test project within the solution called MyProjectTest. There are multiple functions I want to test but my problem is that most functions refer to a global variable within a module in MyProject.

So when I call a function and pass it the required parameters everything is fine until it tries to reference this global variable which it thinks is empty. I can set this global variable in my test project, but it keeps looking at MyProject global variable instead of the one I made in MyProjectTest.

Can I create an instance of MyProject and then set this variable there ? How do i get the function to look at MyProjectTest variables.

Answer (score 0):

I have just started doing Unit Testing and have this issue in legacy code where I cannot realistically change the use of global variables. I have searched and found no solutions. To resolve this I created a Subroutine in the code being tested that initializes the global values needed for the test and call it from the Class Initialize of the test class.

I have not decided how to handle this in the deployment yet. Current thought is to have a compiler option so the initialization code does not get compiled in the Release and assigning Traits to the tests that should not run when compiling the Release version.

```
<TestClass()> _
Public Class modLanguagesTest
    Private testContextInstance As TestContext
~~~~
    <ClassInitialize()> _
    Public Shared Sub modLanguagesTestInitialize(ByVal testContext As TestContext)
        UnitTest_InitializeGlobals()
    End Sub
~~~
    <TestMethod()> _
    Public Sub WHEN_No_Locale_Matches_EXPECT_String_Empty()
        Dim strSystemLanguage As String = "en-US"
        Dim expected As String = String.Empty
        Dim actual As String

        actual = modLanguages.getMatchingLanguage(strSystemLanguage)
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual)
    End Sub
End Class


Public Module modLanguages                         <=== this is module under test
~~~~
    Public Sub UnitTest_InitializeGlobals()        <=== this initializes globals for the test
        g_colUILanguageValues = New Collections.SortedList
        g_colUILanguageValues.Add(0, "English en-GB")
        g_colUILanguageValues.Add(1, "Deutsch de-DE")
    End Sub
~~~~
    ''' <summary>                                  <=== this is the function being tested
    ''' Searches the installed languages for a match to the passed string
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="strSystemLanguage">string to match</param>
    ''' <returns>Installed Language parameter that matches the passed string</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Function getMatchingLanguage(ByVal strSystemLanguage As String) As String
        Dim strInstalledLanguage As String
        Dim strRslt As String = String.Empty

        For Each lng In g_colUILanguageValues.Values
            strInstalledLanguage = lng.ToString
            If strInstalledLanguage.Contains(strSystemLanguage) Then
                strRslt = strInstalledLanguage
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        Return strRslt

    End Function
```